# Return strings within a range of dates in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date

I'm working on a script which looks at a group of files, checks to see to if they have any lines within a "@due" tag followed by a date range, then takes those lines and prints them to a separate file. (Basically, I have a set of text files that have items with due dates, and I want a daily synopsis of what is overdue, due today, and due within the next 4 days.)

Right now, I'm doing this with blunt force:

```
tom1 = (Time.now + 86400).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
tom2 = (Time.now + (86400 * 2)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
tom3 = (Time.now + (86400 * 3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

etc., and then:

```
if line =~ /@due\(#{tom1}\)/
found_completed = true
project += line.gsub(/@due\(.*?\)/,'').strip + " **1 day**" + "\n" + "\t"
end

if line =~ /@due\(#{tom2}\)/
found_completed = true
project += line.gsub(/@due\(.*?\)/,'').strip + " **2 days**" + "\n" + "\t"
end
```

Etc. etc.

I do this for 30 days in the past, the current day, and then 4 days in the future. I'm wondering, perhaps if I require "Date" instead of "Time," and then set up some sort of range, if there isn't a more elegant way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use date ranges, you're going to have to start parsing dates from your lines, instead of using regular expression matching.

Comment: Instead of `line =~ /@due\(#{tom1}\)/` you could simply do `line["@due(#{tom1})"]` which should be faster

Comment: ruby 2.0 has a next_day method on the Date class that may help if you're doing 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work, or with light massaging will work. I tested it on a very few dates and it worked for them. When you run the script, make sure you pass in the date through the command line as YYYY-MM-DD. I wrote to the console rather than another file just so I could check the test values easier. I used the begin-rescue block in the event that a line in your file did not have a well formed date value.

```
require 'date'

def due(due_dates)
    due_dates.each do |x|
        puts x
    end
end

today = Date.parse(ARGV.shift)

f = File.readlines('path_to_file')

due_today = []
due_within_four = []
past_due = []
f.each do |line|
    begin
        d = Date.parse(line)
        due_today << line if d == today
        due_within_four << line if (today+1..today+4).cover? d
        past_due << line if (today-30..today-1).cover? d
    rescue 
        next
    end
end

puts "DUE TODAY"
due(due_today)

puts "\nDUE WITHIN FOUR DAYS"
due(due_within_four)

puts "\nOVERDUE"
due(past_due)
```

Comment: I know this could be cleaned up quite a bit, this is just a quick and dirty.

Comment: You can actually use dates in Ranges: `today = Date.today; (today-30..today).cover?(today-7)`

Comment: Can we build on the Range idea? That seems like the most simple and can work within the script as it's already set up. I've been trying `today = Date.today; past = ((today-30).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')..(today).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`. The "today" one is working just fine, but the "past" one isn't finding any of the earlier dates.

Comment: @craigeley Is there a reason you are using strftime? It changes the format of the Date objects you are storing.

Comment: I'm using strftime because that is how the dates I'm looking for are formatted, for example, '@due(2013-06-12)'

Comment: @craigeley In my test file I formatted the dates the same way and it worked without strftime. Try it without and see what happens

Comment: Okay, cool—I did get that to work. It's not exactly the formatting I'm looking for it, but it is the general principle. I'm SUPER new to Ruby, so I'm still fumbling around myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some might argue it's overkill for a relatively simply situation like this but I like using the ice_cube (https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) gem for recurring date functionality. Here's an example of how you could approach it, salt to taste.

```
require 'ice_cube'

lines = File.readlines('myfile.txt')
start_date = Time.now - 30 * 86400
end_date   = Time.now + 4 * 86400
matched_lines = IceCube::Schedule.new(start_date).tap do |schedule|
    schedule.add_recurrence_rule IceCube::Rule.daily
end.occurrences(end_date).collect do |time|
    formatted_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    lines.map { |line| line if line =~ /@due\(#{formatted_time}\)/ }
end.flatten
```